# Compare arrays with condition and check if they are same length

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to compare 2 arrays of objects, and to check if 1 array has all elements with the same `id` and `role` of the other array. The arrays look like this:

```
const allUsers = [
 { id: 1, roleId: 123, username: 'User1', roles:['admin'] }
 { id: 2, roleId: 123, username: 'User2', roles:['admin'] }
 { id: 3, roleId: 123, username: 'User3', roles:['admin'] }
 { id: 4, roleId: 123, username: 'User4', roles:['admin'] }
 { id: 5, roleId: 233, username: 'User5', roles:['admin'] }
]
// first example - here I have to return false
const selectedUsers = [
 { id: 1, roleId: 123, username: 'User1', roles:['admin'] }
 { id: 2, roleId: 123, username: 'User2', roles:['admin'] }
 { id: 5, roleId: 233, username: 'User5', roles:['admin'] }
]
// 2nd example - here I can return true
const selectedUsers = [
 { id: 1, roleId: 123, username: 'User1', roles:['admin'] }
 { id: 2, roleId: 123, username: 'User2', roles:['admin'] }
]
```

What I need is the following - here in `selectedUsers` I have selected all users with `roleId: 233` and `roles:['admin']`, so I would need to set some flag to false. If i didn't have that user, If I just had users 1/2 with `roleId: 123`, I could delete them because there are more users with the same roleId and `roles: ['admin']`

I need to compare these arrays somehow and check if all users with same `roleId` and `role` are trying to be removed.

Any tips on what would be the easiest solution?

EDIT: As i wrote in the comment, I am trying to check if I can remove the `selectedUsers`, but i can do that only if there is at least 1 different user left with the same roleId and 'admin' in `allUsers` array

Comment: @B001ᛦ I am trying to check if I can remove the selectedUsers, but I can do that only if there is at least 1 admin left with the same roleId in allUsers array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return this in your function:

```
return selectedUsers.every(u => 
    allUsers.filter(a =>
        a.roleId === u.roleId && a.roles.join('') === u.roles.join(''))
            .length > 1);
```

- The `every()` makes sure every `selectedUser` satisfies a condition
- That condition being tested in the `filter()` which makes sure that you need to have at least 2 similar users with the same `roleId` and `roles` as the user being checked. Note that it's 2 not 1, as `allUsers` also currently includes the user being checked, which will be potentially deleted after you return `true` from this function.
- Notes: The `join()` trick does a simple deep-equal comparison of two `roles` arrays (you can't just check `u.roles == a.roles`) provided that the roles should be listed in a consistent order (in case of more than one roles).